# Nodemailer - Sendmail transporter Error: TypeError: this._spawn is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sendmail, nodemailer

Following the [online guide of Nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/transports/sendmail/) and using the [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer), I created a basic sendmail transporter in my React project, looking like this:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("ok")
        let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({"sendmail": true});
        transporter.sendMail({
            from: '"Firstname Lastname" <me@example.com>', // sender address
            to: "me@example.com", // list of receivers
            subject: "Hello", // Subject line
            html: "<b>My mail from React!</b>" // html body
        });
}
```

However, when clicking on the submit, button, I receive following error:

> TypeError: this._spawn is not a function

Does someone now why this problem occurs? Whenever I find other examples about sendmail, they all look semi-exaclty like the above.

### Error code

**Location:**
 
*node_modules/nodemailer/lib/sendmail-transport/index.js*

**Code block**

```
try {
    sendmail = this._spawn(this.path, args);  <<<<<<<<<<<< This is where the error occurs <<<<<<<<<<<<
} catch (E) {
    this.logger.error(
        {
            err: E,
            tnx: 'spawn',
            messageId
        },
        'Error occurred while spawning sendmail. %s',
        E.message
    );
    return callback(E);
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming your code sample is from your front-end React client, correct? I don't think `nodemailer` can be used in the browser this way. I'm not sure, but I feel like the `TypeError: this._spawn is not a function` is a reference to Node's [`child_process.spawn()` function](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options), maybe indicating that the Nodemailer module is trying to access that particular back-end Node process which isn't accessible from the browser. I don't see anything wrong with your actual `transporter` code.

Comment: @ty2k I added the location of the file where the error occurs & added the part of the code where it happens. What I actually want to do, is to create a very simple textarea and button form that sends an e-mail to my mailbox without any SMTP data given. The reason why it has to be this simple, is because I will need to implement this multiple times dynamically with different mail address and don't want to set up SMTP settings for each e-mail address. That's why I thought nodemailer's sendmail was the solution. Can you give me some advice / direction to how I could achieve this?

Comment: I think `nodemailer` can do what you want, but the logic to do so needs to be in your Node.js back-end and not in your React front-end. The front-end should simply send a request to the back-end. Check out [Create a contact form with Nodemailer, React, and Express (medium.com)](https://medium.com/@binhchung48/create-a-contact-form-with-nodemailer-react-js-and-express-js-7757d41e2448), it should give you almost everything you need. :)